# Inconsistent spacing in cases environment

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting, cases

I'm working with the document below and noticed a bizarre inconsistency in vertical spacing in the cases environment. Ideally, I'd like the red and blue boxes to be the same height no matter what the cases are (bizarrely, they have height 0 in the example with integrals). I'd also like to have the equation numbered as in the example, with a single number (1) centered vertically. This is not possible with some possible fixes e.g. \subnumcases. Can anyone provide a workable solution to this problem that is more general than manually altering spacing every time I use cases? [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{cases}[1][\lbrace]{%
  \def\@ldelim{#1}
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{\lbrace}{\@ldelim}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    a & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
    b & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle \int ... & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
    \displaystyle \int ... & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first blue box have its baseline aligned with the top of 'f' rather than 'a'?

Comment: tex almost never tries to equalise space from bottom of descenders on one line to top of character on next, it tries to equalize baseline-to-baseline space. so it never even considers your red box

Comment: "bizarrely, they have height 0 in the example with integrals)." stretch braces are allowed to be smaller than the content by `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` so it is by design (and user setable) that they are smaller than the integrals here.

Comment: Off topic: These are essentially one-line equations, so should use the `equation` environment, not `align`.

Comment: In my opinion your first formula looks OK, while the second one could benefit from some space between the two lines, since the integrals come too close. These things look differently in different fonts, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHOo7.png) is the last formula with Xcharter (and more space between the lines). There it happens to fit fine for this case.